# Embedded submanifold of embedded submanifold in Euclidean space

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

If $S$ is an embedded submanifold in $M$ then for each $p\in S$, there exists a chart $U$ in $M$ on which $U\cap S$ is defined by the vanishing of some coordinates.

My question is, does this then imply that $U\cap S$ is an embedded submanifold of $S$ (because then it is defined by the vanishing of no coordinate functions) and therefore $U\cap S$ is an embedded submanifold of $M$?

Comment: What is the definition of embedded submanifold that you are using?

Comment: @ArcticChar vanishing of coordinate functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, $U\cap S$ is an *open* submanifold of $S$ by definition of the subspace topology on $S$, so in particular it is an embedded submanifold of $S$, since every open submanifold is embedded.

Comment: but also this implies that $U\cap S$ is an embedded submanifold of $M$, right?

Comment: @monoidaltransform: Yes, that's also true. The definition of being a submanifold is a local one, so this is essentially equivalent to what it means for $S$ to be a submanifold.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it!